# InputStream writing to OutputStream taking too long Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am trying to fetch images from my web API, and populate these into a recyclerview. I am getting my pictures via my Web API - I use Retrofit 2.0 to consume the API. The images have been compressed (they range from 100 - 300kb in size). The issue I am facing is that the while loop to write contents of the inputstream to output stream takes long - I found that this loop takes anywhere between 7 to 11 seconds for each image. Here is the code to get pictures:

```
        if (postList.size() > 0) {
            for (HousePostViewModel model : postList) {
                Response<ResponseBody> pictureCall = service.getHousePostImage("Bearer " + sharedPreferences.getString("authorization_token", ""), model.getHousePostID(), currentActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.homenet_client_string)).execute();
                if (pictureCall.isSuccessful()) {
                    try {
                        InputStream inputStream = null;
                        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
                        File profileFile = new File(currentActivity.getExternalCacheDir() + File.separator + generateRandomString()+"tempImage3.jpg");
                        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(pictureCall.body().byteStream());
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(profileFile);
                        int c;
                        Log.i("START", "Starting to read the image");
                        long timeInMS = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        //This is the loop, where images take long to write to outputstream
                        while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                            outputStream.write(c);
                        }
                        Picture picture = new Picture(profileFile);
                        pictureList.add(picture);
                        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long finalTime = finish - timeInMS;
                        Log.i("END", "Finished Reading file in " +finalTime+" ms");
                        inputStream.close();
                        outputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception error) {

                    }
                } else {
                    errorString += pictureCall.errorBody().string();
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    errorString += postCall.errorBody().string();
}
```

What would you guys suggest I try, or do? Or is there another way of getting image data from an API?

Comment: Try reading and writing in blocks of at least 1 kb, instead of one byte at a time. *FYI:* [`Files.copy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) uses an **8 kb** buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(c);
}
```

Use buffered I/O. Wish I had a buck for every time I've posted this:

```
char[] buffer = new char[8192];
int count;
while ((count = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

... and you should wrap a `BufferedOutputStream` around the `FileOutputStream`, thus:

```
outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(profileFile));
```

You also need to close the streams *before* creating the `Picture`.